# Howdy BotKit to Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, botkit

We have used Ms Bot framework and we like the functionality it provides.
On looking at BotKit (https://github.com/howdyai/botkit), bot kit support FB Messenger and MS Bot Framework, Twilio,Slack. MS Bot Framework itself supports Facebook Messenger capabilities. Why is BotKit so popular when one of its core functions is to convert to another Bot Framework in this case MS. Is the plan on BotKit to catch up with MS Bot Framework ? There are lot of contributors on BotKit, where is it being extensively used?
Any help in this area would be great as i am losing my sleep over this.

Comment: I've never used it, but here's the founder talking about it in May 2016: https://www.twilio.com/signal/2016/video/5nv4horeAowkEu6Y26Gq4i/howdy

Comment: BotKit just launched a Bot Studio, with NLP powered by luis.ai. https://studio.botkit.ai/